# Pullback of a (p,q) form

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-forms

I am currently trying to explicitly calculate the pullback of a (p,q) form. So let's say that we have $\omega \in \Omega_X^{p,q}(U)$ and it is $\omega=\sum_{I \in I(p,n),J\in I(q,n)}\omega_{I,J}dz^I \wedge d\overline{z}^J$.

How can I now calculate the pullback $f^*\omega$ with some (holomorphic) $f: V \rightarrow U$ in local coordinates? I would really appreciate it if someone could show me how this can be done.

Note:
I already tried it myself but for some reason I can't handle the expression $df^I \wedge d\bar{f}^J$ that appears when I try to use $f^*(dz\wedge d\overline z) = df\wedge d\overline{f}$ with multi indices.

Comment: I suggest starting by figuring out what $f^*dz^i$ and $f^*d\bar z^i$ are.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f^*dz^i= df^i = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial z^j}dz_j + \frac{\partial f^j}{\partial \bar{z}^j} d\bar{z}^j$? For some reason I can't figure it out with the multi indices.

Comment: What about $f^*d\bar z$?

Comment: Also, you should use local coordinates on $U$, so $f = (f^1,\dots,f^m)$.

Comment: This should be the same just with coefficients $\frac{\partial \bar{f}^i}{\partial z}$ and  $\frac{\partial \bar{f}^i}{\partial \bar{z}}$ shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. Now use different variables to lessen confusion. Suppose you have $\omega =dw^i\wedge d\bar w^j$ on $U$. What’s $f^*\omega$?

Comment: It is $f^*\omega = d(\omega\circ f)^i \wedge d(\overline\omega \circ f)^j$.

Comment: You have to be clear about what’s $w$ and what’s $\omega$. Also, recall that $f^*(\omega\wedge\theta)=(f^*\omega)\wedge(f^*\theta)$.

Comment: Just to check, do you know how the computation goes for the general case of a smooth map between two *real* manifolds with respective local coordinate systems?

Comment: Yes I do know how to calculate the pullback in local coordinates, if I only have $\sum_{|J|=p} w_J dx^J$ My only problem is that I can't handle the two multi indices in the wedge product.

Comment: then it seems to me that you just need to use the holomorphicity condition on $f$, which implies $\partial_{\bar{z}^j}f^i=0$ for all indices. Also, $\bar{f}$ will be anti-holomorphic, so that $\partial_{z^j}\bar{f}^i=0$.

Comment: A related question with answer that you might find useful:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715339/261022