# Show that the natural pull-back $f^*: \mathcal{A}^k(V) \to \mathcal{A}^k(V)$ induces maps $\mathcal{A}^{p,q}(V) \to \mathcal{A}^{p,q}(U)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

> Let $f: U \to V$ be a holomorphic map. Show that the natural pull-back $f^* \mathcal{A}^k(V) \to \mathcal{A}^k(V)$ induces maps $\mathcal{A}^{p,q}(V) \to \mathcal{A}^{p,q}(U)$.

Is this just restricing $f^*$ to the subset $\mathcal{A}^{p,q}(V)$ of $\mathcal{A}^k(V)$? We know that $$\mathcal{A}^k(V) = \bigoplus_{p+q=k}\mathcal{A}^{p,q}(V)$$ so we should have a projection $\pi^{p,q}:\mathcal{A}^k(U) \to \mathcal{A}^{p,q}(U)$ and an inclusion $i^{p,q}:\mathcal{A}^{p,q}(V) \to \mathcal{A}^k(V)$ and combing these would give a map $\pi^{p,q} \circ f^* \circ i^{p,q }:\mathcal{A}^{p,q}(V) \to \mathcal{A}^{p,q}(U)$. Is this what they were after here?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697922/pullbacks-respect-order-of-forms/4698068?noredirect=1#comment9942201_4698068

Answer (score 1):

What they want you to prove is that when $\omega \in A^{p,q}(V) \subset A^{p + q}(V)$, $f^*\omega$ which belongs to $A^{p + q}(U)$ is in fact in $A^{p,q}(U) \subset A^{p + q}(U)$. It implies with you notations that $\pi^{p,q} \circ f^* \circ i^{p,q} = f^* \circ i^{p,q}$.

To prove it, take $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $u \in U$ and $(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \in (T_uU)^k$ where $k = p + q$. We have,
\begin{align*}
(f^*\omega)_u(zx_1,\ldots,zx_k) & = \omega_{f(u)}(df(u)(zx_1),\ldots,df(u)(zx_k))\\
& = \omega_{f(u)}(zdf(u)(x_1),\ldots,zdf(u)(x_k))\\
& \textrm{ because $df(u)$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear, because $f$ is holomorphic},\\
& = z^p\overline{z}^q\omega_{f(u)}(df(u)(x_1),\ldots,df(u)(x_k))\\
& \textrm{ because $\omega$ is a $(p,q)$ form},\\
& = z^p\overline{z}^q(f^*\omega)_u(x_1,\ldots,x_k).
\end{align*}
It proves that $f^*\omega$ is indeed a $(p,q)$ form.